Any comment on an original way to give a closed form formula for an entire series with coefficients sums of finite GP
I came across a rather fascinating question on the topic of series and sequences given in Hall and Knight's book titled 'Higher Algebra'. It was as follows -

Find the sum of the infinite series 1+(1+b)r+(1+b+$b^2$)$r^2$+(1+b+$b^2$+$b^3$)$r^3$+..., where r and b are both vulgar (common) fractions.

It took me some time, but after some manipulation, I ended up with the correct answer. I detail my methodology in doing the same below -
Let S = 1+(1+b)r+(1+b+$b^2$)$r^2$+(1+b+$b^2$+$b^3$)$r^3$
Then, S = 1+r+br+$r^2$+b$r^2$+$b^2$$r^2$+$r^3$+b$r^3$+$b^2$$r^3$+$b^3$$r^3$+...
=> S = 1+(r+$r^2$+$r^3$+$r^4$+...)+(br+b$r^2$+b$r^3$+b$r^4$...)+($b^2$$r^2$+$b^2$$r^3$+$b^2$$r^4$+$b^2$$r^5$...) and so on.
=> S = 1+r(1+r+$r^2$+$r^3$+...)+br(1+r+$r^2$+$r^3$...)+$b^2$$r^2$(1+r+$r^2$+$r^3$...) and so on.
=> S = 1+(1+r+$r^2$+$r^3$+...)(r+br+$b^2$$r^2$+$b^3$$r^3$...)
=> S = 1+(1+r+$r^2$+$r^3$+...)[r+b(r+b$r^2$+$b^2$$r^3$...)]
The sum of an infinite GP when the absolute value of the common ratio is less than 1 is given by $$\frac{a}{1-r}$$ where a is the first term of the GP and r is the common ratio.
Using this relation, we obtain that
$$S = 1+(\frac{1}{1-r})(r+\frac{br}{1-br})$$
$$=> S = 1+(\frac{1}{1-r})(\frac{r+br-br^2}{1-br})$$
$$=> S = 1+\frac{r+br-br^2}{(1-br)(1-r)}$$
$$=> S = \frac{1}{(1-br)(1-r)}$$
After tediously getting the apt solution, I went onto the web and checked how others had solved the problem. To my surprise, not a single result had been obtained the way I had obtained it.
Hence, I suppose that this post boils down to me asking whether the method that I have employed above is mathematically correct, and if so, I guess this post then turns into me just figuring out a rare and tedious way to do a problem.
Thanks,
a math nerd.

See also this question

To address Is this mathematically correct?, "yes," but you may want to read about "absolute convergence" of (double) series, or "absolute summability" of (double) sequences. Generally, series cannot be manipulated by re-ordering or re-grouping terms.

In connection with the comment of @Andrew D. Hwang : your manipulation of series has been successful but could have led to an erroneous conclusion by grouping in a different way. See here
